# Perl Printing contents of two separate arrays side by side

Tags: arrays, perl

I am interested to print the content of two arrays side by side instead of one after the other.

My arrays are:

```
my @present = ("John", "Mary", "Jimmy", "Kumar", "Ling");
my @absent = ("Joanne", "Charlotte", "Mei");
```

This is how the output should look like:

```
Present    Absent    
=======    ======
John       Joanne
Mary       Charlotte
Jimmy      Mei
Kumar
Ling
```

Looking at the examples using Text::Table seem to suggest that contents are printed row by row. Is there a way the contents are printed column by column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could restructure your data, so that you can use Text::Table.
It also recognizes ANSI color escapes, for example

But for this simple case this works fine. (depending on your data, don't forget to decode utf8 before calculating the string length)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use List::Util qw / max /;
my @present = qw/ John Mary Jimmy Kumar Ling /;
my @absent = qw/ Joanne Charlotte Mei /;
my @columns = (\@present, \@absent);
my @headers = qw/ Present Absent /;
my @width;

for my $i (0 .. $#headers) {
    unshift @{ $columns[ $i ] }, '=' x length $headers[ $i ];
    unshift @{ $columns[ $i ] }, $headers[ $i ];
    $width[ $i ] = max map { length } @{ $columns[ $i ] };
}

my $rows = max map { $#$_ } @columns;
for my $i (0 .. $rows ) {
    my $fmt = join '   ', map { '%-' . $width[ $_ ] . 's' } 0 .. $#headers;
    my @col = map { $columns[ $_ ]->[ $i ] // '' } 0 ..$#headers;
    printf "$fmt\n", @col;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

THis code may help you:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $format = "%-10s\t%-10s\n";
my @present = ("John", "Mary", "Jimmy", "Kumar", "Ling");
my @absent = ("Joanne", "Charlotte", "Mei");
my $maxrows = $#present > $#absent ?  $#present : $#absent; 
printf($format,"Present","Absent");
printf($format,"=======","======");
for my $rownum ( 0..$maxrows ) { 
    printf ( $format, $present[$rownum] // '', $absent[$rownum] // '' );

    }
```

Output:

```
Present     Absent    
=======     ======    
John        Joanne    
Mary        Charlotte 
Jimmy       Mei       
Kumar                 
Ling
```